# Contain absolutely positioned 100% width DIV inside a TD in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I found several questions addressing similar problems, but each solution has a particularity that prevents it from applying to this situation...

My issue is that I want an absolutely positioned, 100% width, div inside a table cell.  I can't use fixed widths or heights anywhere because all the content can vary in width and height.  I want the div to be positioned from the bottom of the cell height, which is influenced by the (variable) height of the content in the next cell.

The code below works fine in IE8 (yeah, still have to support it...), IE11 and Chrome — the red div stays contained within the left table cell.  In Firefox however, the div is actually sized according to the width of the TABLE, covering part of the cell on the right.

What can I do to make it work in Firefox?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AGYGH/

HTML:

```
<table id="OuterTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="TableCell">
            <table id="InnerTable" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Dummy text of varying length</td>
                    <td>Dummy</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="AbsoluteDiv">
                <div id="InnerDivLeft">Left Div</div>
                <div id="InnerDivRight">Right Div</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
                <option>Varying length options</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#OuterTable {
    position:relative;
}
#TableCell {
    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;
}
#AbsoluteDiv {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:30px;
}
#InnerDivLeft {
    float:left;
}
#InnerDivRight {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: That's because *The effect of [`position:relative`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) on `table-*-group`, `table-row`, `table-column`, `table-cell`, and `table-caption` elements is undefined.*

Comment: Try wrapping the content of that cell by a `div` element like so: http://jsfiddle.net/AGYGH/7/

Comment: @Hashem : I understand the _undefined_ part, although it works as expected in IE and Chrome, I still want a solution for Firefox.
As for the wrapper in your example — it fixes the width problem, but Firefox then displays the red div ABOVE the containing cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this problem as well. According to the spec, table cells cannot be positioned. Meaning FireFox is doing it *right*, and everyone else is doing it "right".

Kinda hacky, but you could always use div's with "display: table-cell" THEN position them relative.

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/) has a good JS alternative for the issue.

Comment: Not sure about `display:table-cell` (tried without success), but thanks for the JS alternative - since I already use jQuery, that's a winner !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Seth for pointing me to the JavaScript solution, which has the added benefit of also fixing small padding/margin issues on IE in my 'real world' usage.

So, I've wrapped the entire content of `<td id="TableCell">` with a `<div class="wrapper">` (as suggested by Hashem) and used jQuery to size its height to the actual height of the table cell:

```
$('#TableCell div.wrapper').height($('#TableCell').height());
```

Revised Demo (with the added wrapper colored blue) : http://jsfiddle.net/AGYGH/9/